# Change user email in Django without using django-profiles

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-profiles

In my Django application I would like the user to be able to change the email address. I've seen solution of StackOverflow pointing people to django-profiles. Unfortunately I don't want to use a full fledged profile module to accomplish a tiny feat of changing the users email. Has anyone seen this implemented anywhere. The email address verification procedure by sending a confirmation email is a requisite in this scenario.

I've spent a great a deal of time trying to a find a solution that works but to no avail.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that someone did write their own. It allows users to change their email addresses and sends confirmation emails.

[django-emailchange](http://code.google.com/p/django-emailchange/)

Answer (score 2):

The email address belongs to the user model, so there's no need to use profiles to let users update their email. Create a [model form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) from the user model that has only email as a field, then provide that form in your view and process it. Something like:

```
class UserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

def my_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        user_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('form_success_screen'))
    else:
        user_form = UserInfoForm()
    return render_to_response('my-template.html', {'user_form': user_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Note that if the form is successful, I'm returning a HttpResponseRedirect to send the user to another page. In this case, I'm looking up a named url from my urls file.

Comment: Sorry if I seem demanding but have you come across a snippet which sends a verification email. I'm good with Python but I haven't implemented anything similar in Django. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: Try django-email-confirmation: http://github.com/jtauber/django-email-confirmation/

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if it's a new requirement of Django 1.4 but I tried Tom's suggestion:

```
class UserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email')
```

and got a fields error.  You must have a trailing comma after each field (or so that's what solved my error):

```
fields = ('email',)
```

fixed the problem